# Take screenshot of a FMX form from another process, even if the form is not topmost / modal

Tags: windows, delphi, screenshot, firemonkey

I am currently trying to take a screenshot of a 2D Firemonkey (FMX) form from another process.

The following is using a well-known method based of GDI, using a BitBlt() to produce a bitmap, and WIC to save it to a PNG file.

```delphi
{...}
uses
  system.UITypes,
  system.SysUtils,
  system.Hash,
  {$IF Defined(MSWINDOWS)}
  winapi.Windows,
  Winapi.Direct3D9,
  WinApi.D3DX9,
  Winapi.Wincodec,
  WinApi.ActiveX,
  {$ENDIF}
  { some internal units }
  path.types,
  path.utils,
  os.utils;

{...}


Type
  TWindowSnapshot = record
     window_handle: THandle;    // handle to window
     process_id: Cardinal;      // PID of the process
     window_rect: TRect;        // position of the window
     title: string;             // title
     file_path: string;         // path to the window's image file
  end;

  TWindowSnapshots = Tarray<TWindowSnapshot>;


procedure HRCHECK(r: HRESULT); inline;
begin
  if r <> S_OK then abort;
end;

function pad(s,g:integer): integer; inline;
begin
 dec(g);
 result := (s + g) and not g;
end;


function WICSavePixelsToPng(r: TRect; stride: cardinal; pixels: PByte; filePath: string): HRESULT;
var
  factory: IWICImagingFactory;
  encoder: IWICBitmapEncoder;
  frame: IWICBitmapFrameEncode;
  encoderOptions: IPropertyBag2;
  stream: IWICStream;
  pf: TGUID;
  coInit : HResult;

begin
  result := E_INVALIDARG;
  if not assigned(pixels) then exit;
  if (filepath = '')  then exit;
  coInit := CoInitialize(nil);
  pf := GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppBGRA;
  result := CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WICImagingFactory, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IWICImagingFactory, factory);
  if result <> S_OK then exit;
  result := factory.CreateStream(&stream);
  if result <> S_OK then exit;
  result := stream.InitializeFromFilename(PWideChar(filePath), GENERIC_WRITE);
  if result <> S_OK then exit;
  result := factory.CreateEncoder(GUID_ContainerFormatPng, TGUID.Empty, encoder);
  if result <> S_OK then exit;
  result := encoder.Initialize(stream, WICBitmapEncoderNoCache);
  if result <> S_OK then exit;
  result := encoder.CreateNewFrame(frame, encoderOptions);
  if result <> S_OK then exit;
  result := frame.Initialize(nil);
  if result <> S_OK then exit;
  result := frame.SetSize(r.width, r.height);
  if result <> S_OK then exit;
  result := frame.SetPixelFormat(pf);
  if result <> S_OK then exit;
  if pf <> GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppBGRA then
  begin
    assert(false,'ToDo');
  end;
  inc(pixels,(r.Left*4) + r.Top * stride);
  result := frame.WritePixels(r.height, stride, stride * r.height, pixels);
  if result <> S_OK then exit;
  result := frame.Commit();
  if result <> S_OK then exit;
  result := encoder.Commit();
  if (coInit <> 0) then
    CoUninitialize();
end;

function take_window_snapshot_GDI(win_handle: THandle; PID: Cardinal; out cs: TWindowSnapshot; const image_folder: string): boolean;
    var
      Wr: TRect;
      HdcSRC: HDC;
      hDCDest: HDC;
      hBmp: HBITMAP;
      hOld: HGDIOBJ;
      hFlags: Cardinal;
      l: integer;
      src_shot,dst_shot,lsrc,ldst: PByte;
      sr: PRGBTriple;
      dr: PRGBQuad;
      buff_size: cardinal;
      x,y, src_stride, dst_stride: integer;
      bi: tagBITMAPINFO;
    
    begin
      result := false;
      cs.window_handle := win_handle;
      cs.title := '';
      cs.window_rect := TRect.Empty;
      cs.process_id := 0;
      try
        hFlags := GetWindowLong(win_handle,GWL_STYLE);
        if (hFlags and (WS_DLGFRAME or WS_POPUP)) = 0 then exit;
        if (hFlags and WS_VISIBLE) = 0 then exit;
        GetWindowRect(win_handle,Wr);
        if (Wr.Width = 0) or (Wr.Height = 0) then exit;
        L := GetWindowTextLength(win_handle);
        if L > 0 then
        begin
          setlength(cs.title,L);
          GetWindowText(win_handle,pchar(cs.title),L+1);
        end;
    
        { reserve memory for bitmaps }
        src_stride := pad((wr.Width * 3),4);
        dst_stride := pad((wr.Width * 4),4);
        buff_size := src_stride * wr.Height;
        getmem(src_shot,buff_size);
        if not assigned(src_shot) then exit;
        getmem(dst_shot,dst_stride * wr.Height);
        if not assigned(src_shot) then
        begin
          freemem(src_shot);
          exit;
        end;
        try
          try
            HdcSRC := GetWindowDC(win_handle);
            HdcDest := CreateCompatibleDC(HdcSRC);
            SetStretchBltMode(HdcDest, COLORONCOLOR);
            HBmp := CreateCompatibleBitmap(HdcSRC,Wr.Width,wr.Height);
            hOld := SelectObject(hDCDest,hBmp);
            BitBlt(hDCDest,0,0,wr.width,wr.Height,HdcSRC,0,0,SRCCOPY);
    
            { target bitplane is 24 bits RGB }
            bi := default(tagBITMAPINFO);
            bi.bmiHeader.biSize := sizeof(TBitmapInfoHeader);
            bi.bmiHeader.biWidth := wr.Width;
            bi.bmiHeader.biHeight := wr.Height;
            bi.bmiHeader.biPlanes := 1;
            bi.bmiHeader.biBitCount := 24;
            bi.bmiHeader.biCompression := BI_RGB;
            GetDIBits(hDCDest,HBmp,0,wr.Height,src_shot,bi,DIB_RGB_COLORS);
    
            { now convert pixels to RGBA, in correct line order.
              On Windows, last line is first in bitmap }
            ldst := dst_shot;
            lsrc := src_shot + (src_stride * wr.Height);
            for y := 0 to wr.Height  - 1 do
            begin
              dec(lsrc,src_stride);
              sr := pointer(lsrc);
              dr := pointer(ldst);
              for x := 0 to wr.Width - 1 do
              begin
                dr.rgbBlue := sr.rgbtBlue;
                dr.rgbRed := sr.rgbtRed;
                dr.rgbGreen := sr.rgbtGreen;
                dr.rgbReserved := 255;
                inc(dr);
                inc(sr);
              end;
              inc(ldst,dst_stride);
            end;
    
            { save to PNG with WIC }
            var tmp_name := Tpath.GetTempFileName('png',false,image_folder);
            wr.Offset(-wr.Left,-wr.top);
            if WICSavePixelsToPng(wr,dst_stride,dst_shot,tmp_name) = S_OK then
            begin
              result := true;
              { rename temp file name to new name if it doesn't exist already }
              var new_name := Tpath.ExtractDirectory(tmp_name) + THashSHA1.GetHashStringFromFile(tmp_name) + '.png';
              if not TPath.FileExists(new_name) then
              begin
                if Tfile.Rename(tmp_name,new_name) then
                begin
                  cs.file_path := '';
                end else begin
                  cs.file_path := new_name;
                end;
              end else begin
                cs.file_path := new_name;
              end;
            end;
            Tfile.Delete(tmp_name);
            result := true;
          finally
            freemem(src_shot);
            freemem(dst_shot);
          end;
        finally
          SelectObject(hDCDest,hold);
          DeleteDC(hDCDest);
          ReleaseDC(win_handle,HdcSRC);
        end;
        except begin
          result := false;
        end;
      end;
    end;
```

This method is working for Delphi forms using VCL, however with forms using Firemonkey (FMX)  2D, it only produces bitmaps filled with BLACK (0) pixels.

I have tried an alternative using Direct3D9, that is working for Firemonkey form, however with a limitation I'll explain after the code snippet

```delphi
function Take_window_snapshot_D3D(win_handle: THandle; PID: Cardinal; out cs: TWindowSnapshot; const image_folder: string): boolean;
var
  D3D: IDirect3D9;
  D3DDevice: IDirect3DDevice9;
  mode: D3DDISPLAYMODE;
  device: IDirect3DDevice9;
  surface: IDirect3DSurface9;
  parameters: D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS;
  rc: D3DLOCKED_RECT;
  pitch: UINT;
  shot: PByte;
  shot_size: cardinal;
  adapter: cardinal;
  wr: TRect;
  hCurWnd: THandle;
  hCurThreadID: Cardinal;
  L: integer;
  hFlags: cardinal;
  hr: HRESULT;

begin
  result := false;
  cs := default(TWindowSnapshot);
  try
    { get the window type }
    hFlags := GetWindowLong(win_handle,GWL_STYLE);
    if (hFlags and (WS_DLGFRAME or WS_POPUP)) = 0 then exit;
    if (hFlags and WS_VISIBLE) = 0 then exit;
    { size }
    GetWindowRect(win_handle,Wr);
    if (Wr.Width = 0) or (Wr.Height = 0) then exit;
    { title }
    L := GetWindowTextLength(win_handle);
    if L > 0 then
    begin
      setlength(cs.title,L);
      GetWindowText(win_handle,pchar(cs.title),L+1);
    end;
    cs.window_handle := win_handle;
    cs.window_rect := wr;
    cs.process_id := PID;

    { Direct3D capture }
    adapter := D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT;
    D3D := Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);
    HRCHECK(D3D.GetAdapterDisplayMode(adapter,mode));
    parameters := default(D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS);
    parameters.Windowed := TRUE;
    parameters.BackBufferCount := 1;
    parameters.BackBufferHeight := mode.Height;
    parameters.BackBufferWidth := mode.Width;
    parameters.SwapEffect := D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    parameters.hDeviceWindow := win_handle;

    { create device & capture surface }
    HRCHECK(d3d.CreateDevice(adapter, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, win_handle, D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, @parameters, device));
    { create surface }
    HRCHECK(device.CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(mode.Width, mode.Height, D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM, &surface, nil));

    { bring our window to front }
    hCurWnd := GetForegroundWindow;
    hCurThreadID := GetCurrentThreadId;
    AttachThreadInput(PID,hCurThreadID,TRUE);
    SetWindowPos(win_handle,HWND_TOPMOST,0,0,0,0,SWP_NOSIZE or SWP_NOMOVE);
    SetWindowPos(win_handle,HWND_NOTOPMOST,0,0,0,0,SWP_SHOWWINDOW or SWP_NOSIZE or SWP_NOMOVE);
    SetForegroundWindow(win_handle);
    SetFocus(win_handle);
    SetActiveWindow(win_handle);
    AttachThreadInput(PID,hCurThreadID,false);

    { Obtain stride value to allocate buffer }
    HRCHECK(surface.LockRect(rc,nil,0));
    pitch := rc.Pitch;
    HRCHECK(surface.UnlockRect());
    shot_size := pitch*mode.Height;
    getmem(shot,shot_size);
    if not assigned(shot) then abort;

    try
      { get surface data }
      HRCHECK(device.GetFrontBufferData(0, surface));
      { copy surface data }
      HRCHECK(surface.LockRect(rc,nil,0));
      move(rc.pBits^,shot^,shot_size);
      HRCHECK(surface.UnlockRect());

      { save snapshot to file using WIC, using a temporary file name first }
      var tmp_name := Tpath.GetTempFileName('png',false,image_folder);
      if WICSavePixelsToPng(wr,pitch,shot,tmp_name) = S_OK then
      begin
        result := true;
        { rename temp file name to new name if it doesn't exist already }
        var new_name := Tpath.ExtractDirectory(tmp_name) + THashSHA1.GetHashStringFromFile(tmp_name) + '.png';
        if not TPath.FileExists(new_name) then
        begin
          if Tfile.Rename(tmp_name,new_name) then
          begin
            cs.file_path := '';
          end else begin
            cs.file_path := new_name;
          end;
        end else begin
          cs.file_path := new_name;
        end;
      end;
      Tfile.Delete(tmp_name);
    finally
      FreeMem(shot);
    end;
    except
      result := false;
  end;
end;
```

The limitation that I have with the D3D method is that in reality I don't take a snapshot of a specific window but I take a snapshot of the entire screen that I crop after to take only the window of my interest.
For that, I must bring first the target window to front, but in some case this may not be possible. For instance if the target form is behind a modal form, it might be partially or totally hidden, as one can see below

[image]

So, my question : Is it possible to take a snapshot / print a single Firemonkey 2D form from another process, even if the form is not modal / partially covered by another form.

Comment: Hi, great question.  Firemonkey renders using Direct2D / Direct3D on Windows which is a hardware accelerated rendering system. I haven't used that in anger much, but I would expect that you would need to use that engine to capture any windows that are not visible.  I don't know if this will help you, but generally getting black pixels is down to pixel conversions and the handling of the alpha channel.  So an image without an alpha channel has an alpha channel of 0 added to it, which then blends the other color values to produce black.

Comment: @RobLambden I've checked every bytes out of BitBlt() and GetDiBits(). In the case of a FMX window, the entire memory is 0-filled thus it's not a pixel format conversion issue, it's just all zeroed.

Comment: So from your investigations this is not an alpha channel handling problem.  So it looks like it comes back to the first part of my comment - as FMX is not drawing with the GDI (It's using Direct2D or Direct3D in Windows) then you need to use the rendering engine (Direct2D / Direct3D) to get the capture if you can.  It's not rendering to a GDI window.  This is beyond my experience but you may find some help in the MS references: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/direct2d-portal

Answer (score -1):

(Sorry for an answer here rather than a comment, which I can't do.)

I know little about working with different processes, but do you realise that FMX has a snapshot ability built in?
`TControl.MakeScreenshot` returns a bitmap of the control (with child controls).  So if you can call that from the other process and return the result, that might solve your problem.
However, this won't meet your needs if you literally need the whole form including the non-client area, as a form doesn't have that method.  If the contents of the form are all you need, and you have a control (e.g. a `TLayout`) filling the form and containing all the child controls, you could use the `.MakeScreenshot` of that bottom control.

And yes, `.MakeScreeshot` works even if something else is covering the form.

Comment: This is a good answer, but does not address the specific part of the question: From another process.  For in process operation this is a good answer.

Comment: Yes, TControl.MakeScreenshot does exactly that, however it is functional only from within the executable.
What I'm trying to achieve is a "support tool" that takes all the snapshots of all the visible forms of the FMX app, thus it's in another process.

Comment: @RobLambden  This is why I would have made it a comment rather than an answer if I could have done that.

Comment: @wesson It wasn't apparent whether the forms you want to take a snapshot of were also ones that you had control over.  If they were, I figured that you could have a method in the photographed apps that would take the screenshot and which could be called from your other process.